# laravel or php question: click button to display the value on the same page

Tags: php, laravel

I have add a button on view page but when I click it, it suppose should be display on the same pages but the result shown me will go to other pages.
Below is the code for views files:

```
<a href="{{url('/cart/add')}}/{{$p->id}}" class="button add-cart-cat button--small card-figcaption-button">Add to Cart</a>
```

and the controller file is:

```
public function addItem($id){

  $pro = products::find($id);
  Cart::add(['id' => $pro->id, 'name' => $pro->pro_name,
  'qty' => 1, 'price' => $pro->pro_price,
  'options' =>[
  'img' => $pro->pro_img
  ]]);
  echo "add to cart successfully";
}
```

In controller above, I have mention will pass the value and then show the message which are successful, yes indeed it come out the result but on other blank pages

By the way, here is the route file I using as well

```
Route::get('cart/add/{id}', 'cartController@addItem');
```

So, is that any way to display the result on the same page when i click the button? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data) for this.

The problem is that you're posting to `/cart/add` and then you're supposed to re-direct the user back to the page - but you don't... instead you're just echoing a response back on the `/cart/add` page.

Instead, do this

```
public function addItem($id){

  $pro = products::find($id);
  Cart::add(['id' => $pro->id, 'name' => $pro->pro_name,
  'qty' => 1, 'price' => $pro->pro_price,
  'options' =>[
  'img' => $pro->pro_img
  ]]);
  //echo "add to cart successfully";


  //Return the user back to the page they came from with a message
  return back()->with('status', 'add to cart successfully');
}
```

Then in your page blade file where the add to cart button is, add this somewhere...

```
//If the session has a message to display, then show it
@if (session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('status') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

If you're not using Bootstrap then customise the message html/css however you wish.

Comment: may i know is that possible to add 1 button to show the message under 1 image? Let Say I got 3 images, when i click the button. Those 3 picture will display the message as well.

Answer (score 0):

**You are not redirecting the page**

you should redirect the route with your message.

**Example**

```
public function addItem($id){
  $pro = products::find($id);
  Cart::add([
      'id' => $pro->id, 'name' => $pro->pro_name,
      'qty' => 1, 'price' => $pro->pro_price,
      'options' =>[
         'img' => $pro->pro_img
       ]
  ]);
  Session::flash('message', "add to cart successfully");
  return Redirect::back();
}
```

Note: you have to put `use Session;` in top of your controller after `namespace`

and then you can receive all the flash messages in blade like this:

```
@if (Session::has('message'))
   <div class="alert alert-info">{{ Session::get('message') }}</div>
@endif
```